# I forgot the lock screen PIN on my Moto G second gen XT-1068

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, usb-debugging, locked-out, unrooting

I forgot the PIN number of the lock screen.

I'm unable to do anything to get into my device as both data connection and Wi-Fi are off and USB debugging is disabled.
Is there any way to enable them?

Otherwise suggest a way to root the device in this state and delete PIN and also to un-root it after the problem is solved.

I don't want to factory reset as I have important data on my phone's internal memory.
My device is un-rooted and runs on Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Try 1000 PINs a day and you're done in ten days. You can shorten that if you omit all primes or other numbers that don't apply to you (like 1337 etc).

Comment: Hmm..Thats a solution but it'll take time and also eat up my patience..

Comment: Rooting will not solve your problem. Root is not some magical thing. Really, if you don't have a data connection, which you would need to do a "reset password" after pin limit reached, your only solution is to factory reset. Sorry, but that's it.

Comment: I understand but I'll keep waiting for someone to come up with a solution..

Comment: I just need to somehow switch on wi-fi/data connection...It'll solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up and activate either Google's Android Device Manager or Motorola Device Policy (Settings/Security/Device Administrators)? Both allow you to set a new password remotely (which would clear the forgotten PIN), via either https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager or the Moto Support Site respectively.

If so it might be worth giving it a try although if you did manage to Factory Reset the phone that should have removed your Google account. I'm surprised that the PIN survived a Factory Reset.